# accessing fingerprint id using Fingerprint API of android(M)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-fingerprint-api

Is there any way to access the enrolled fingerprint id that is being used to authenticate in Android Fingerprint API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , onAuthenticationSuceeded doesn't contain any information for the enrolled finger, hope it will be added in the future released SDK...

```
void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result)
```